# Include tag in TWIG not work，Run is blank

Tags: twig

I don't know it not work.Server environment:

```
Twig:3.0
PHP:7.X
nginx:1.15.11
```

`{{ include 'Include/header.html' }}`

Templates file:

```
|-index.html
|-content.html
|-Include 
    |- head.html
    |- footer.html
```

index.php：

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(ROOT_PATH.'/Templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, [
    'cache' => ROOT_PATH.'/Cache',
     'auto_reload' => true, 
     'debug' => true
]);
echo $twig->render('index.html');
```

index.html：

```
  {{ include 'Include/head.html' }}
  <article>
  body
  <article>
  {{ include 'Include/footer.html' }}
```

it doesn't work,Page is blank.

Comment: it's `{% include .... %}` not `{{ include ... }}`

Comment: You have `header` and `head`, you should clear that up beforehand.

Comment: {% include 'Include/head.html' %}   not work   :(

Comment: Should work as intended.See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/e6qodz). Be sure you have `error_reporting` and `display_errors` enabled, this way twig errors will be displayed as well

Answer (score -2):

First, try comment out if in dev

```
'cache' => ROOT_PATH.'/Cache',
```

then got typo error

```
{{ include 'Include/foother.html' }}
```

to

```
 {{ include 'Include/footer.html' }}
```

I suggest you try do not include any sub twig first and render simple 1 twig first. If success then just include and try again.

Comment: Although the remark about the typo is correct, u'r using the incorrect syntax